# Make a button delete the row on which it is

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a to do list on Excel. I have a button that lets me add a task and some details about the task on a new row.
Basically, I want to add an instruction that, for every new task added, also adds a button at the end of my row that deletes said row (to delete the task when it's over).

Now I have tried this among other things but encountered several problems :

```
Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(cellul.Offset(0, 1).Left, _
    cellul.Offset(0, 1).Top, cellul.Offset(0, 1).Width,_
    cellul.Offset(0, 1).Height)
With btn
    .OnAction = "deletebutton"
    .Caption = "Done !"
    .Name = "Deleteline"
End With
```

And

```
Sub deletebutton()
    Activecell.Entirerow.Delete
End Sub
```

Now that works in the sense that it does give me a button where I want, but as I later have to sort my tasks (by deadline), I am left with buttons that don't move with the sorting (or maybe the `ActiveCell` bit ruins it) and I am left with buttons not deleting the right task.

Does anyone know how I could refer to the row a button is in (that way I could code that in the button's macro), or any other way to make a button delete the row it's actually in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11625379/4099598 might help.

Comment: Could you just name the button based on its row, e.g. "btn_1", and then use the button's name to get the row?

Comment: Full disclosure, I don't like per-row buttons in Excel because I think they are too hard to maintain. I'm wondering why you can't just delete rows in the built-in ways when the task is done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the row in relation to the position of the button that was clicked.  Use the `Application Caller` method to get the name of the clicked button, and the `TopLeftCell` property to get its position.

Using `.Name = "Deleteline"` names all the buttons the same, which makes identifying the clicked button difficult.  Unless you have a good reason for doing this, delete this line.

Refactored `deletebutton` sub (assuming `.Name = "Deleteline"` is removed)

```
Sub deletebutton()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngOld As Range
    Dim msgRes As VbMsgBoxResult


    Set rngOld = ActiveCell
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.EntireRow

    rng.Select
    msgRes = MsgBox("Proceed?", vbOKCancel, "About to Delete this row.")
    If msgRes = vbOK Then
        rng.Delete
    End If
    rngOld.Select
End Sub
```